# how to end a call programmatically in j2me?

Tags: java, java-me

i am developing an application that I need user phone number so I call the server from user's j2me application and I use `platformRequest("tel:" + number);` in my program for this purpose.

But the problem is that I don't know how I can abort the call because a minute ringing is sufficient for server to  retrieving user number.

I want to know is there any API or instruction for canceling a call or some trick for it? for example is pushing the RED button programmatically possible in j2me?

Comment: there is no portable way to do that (search for something like _Java ME security policy_ if you're interested in more details). Find another way to meet application requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to do this, best to get your server to terminate the call somehow.